# Why would HttpContext not contain a "Host" header?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

In my MVC3 application I have a custom controller factory that has `CreateController()`method working as follows:

```
  public IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
   {
       string host = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Host"];
       if( !host.EndsWith( SomeHardcodedString ) ) { // FAILS HERE
           //some special action
       }
       //proceed with controller creation
   }
```

the problem is `host` is null sometimes - I see `NullReferenceException` for some requests and the exception stack trace points exactly at that line.

Why would `null` be retrieved here? How do I handle such cases?

Comment: The `Host` header is only mandatory in HTTP 1.1. Maybe some of your clients are still performing requests using the HTTP 1.0 protocol?

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: Maybe. What can I do to process such requests then?

Comment: According to [the spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.23), you should be able to synthesize this header from the host name (and port number, if any) specified in the request's URL (`Request.Url.Host`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `string host = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host;`

Answer (score 2):

To handle it, you might want to try something like:

```
var host = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host;

if (host != null)
    if(!host.EndsWith("SomeHardcodedString")) 
else
   // Handle it
```